# Is there a way to get deque's internal storage size as vector::capacity?

Tags: c++, deque

I understand that both deque and vector reserve some space for growth. vector::capacity() is able to get the internal reserved space for a vector. Deque doesn't have such a member in the standard. Is there some way to get this information?

Comment: See also Herb Sutter's [Guru of the Week #54:  Using Vector and Deque](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm).

Comment: I read that chapter. There may be no reason to get deque's capacity in reality, but I am just curious.

Comment: What do you want to know the capacity for? In a vector it is clear, growing is a rather expensive operation where all existing object must be moved to a different location in memory, but with dequeues growing is not expensive. That is: capacity is how many elements it can contain before growing becomes painful. And that applies only to vectors.

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to dig into the implementation to figure that out.  The version of `std::deque` that comes with gcc 4.1.1 appears to allocate memory in 512 byte chunks.  But that's as far as I got after 15 minutes of staring at all the underscores and C-style casts to `size_t`.  And then I came across this comment:

> The initial underlying memory layout is a bit complicated...

Answer (score 6):

Not portably. The reason there's no `capacity` member for deque is because it does not use contiguous memory. There's no reason, performance-wise, to consider it.